# How can I get a phpunit.bat after install phpunit via PEAR?

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit, pear

I need a phpunit.bat to configure my NetBeans IDE.

I'm using [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/), and I just install phpunit via pear using these instructions:

Before start using PEAR, Update by downloading last go-pear from http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar and save it into: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3\PEAR

Then:

```
cd C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0>
php -d phar.require_hash=0 PEAR/go-pear.phar
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover components.ez.no
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

After do that I can't find any phpunit.bat or phpunit.php

How can I get a phpunit.bat (or any CLI) after install phpunit via PEAR?

Comment: @edorian: I just update the question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Type:

```
pear config-show
```

look for the `PEAR executables directory`

Your `phpunit.bat` will be there.

**If it isn't:**

```
pear install --alldeps --force phpunit/phpunit
```

and look again.