# What ever happened to PHPUnit's Database Extension?

Tags: php, phpunit

After upgrading to PHPUnit v > 3.5 (I forgot) I kept on getting this error because I imported **PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/TestCase.php**:

```
require_once(...): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I peeked at the PHPUnit folder in my /usr/share/php folder only to find out it isn't there anymore.

In fact a look at the official [source code](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/tree/3.5/PHPUnit/Extensions) reveals that it seems it has been removed.

So for now I am using version 3.4.15. But it's not ideal as assertions on the table are still not supported. For now I am only able to use the CLEAN_INSERT feature which populates my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by installing db unit manually. I downloaded it from [here](http://pear.phpunit.de/). Then I replaced the incomplete Extensions/Database folder with the one from the download.

Answer (score 22):

Your installation seems broken. PHPUnit 3.5 got split up in more seperate packages.

Use `pear install phpunit/dbUnit` to install that part.

Package overview: http://pear.phpunit.de/

---

Or to reinstall everything use: `pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/phpunit`

---

#### 2013 update:

Just use [**`composer`**](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/installation.html#installation.composer) to install PHPUnit. It's less hassle.

Comment: I tried that but this is what I get phpunit/dbUnit is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.0.2

Comment: I'll give a +1 for leading me to http://pear.phpunit.de/ Helped me solve the problem. It seems though that there's something wrong with how PEAR downloads the packages? How come the other files in the Extensions/Database folder are not included?

Comment: @Jeune There was a major Problem/Bug in the pear installer version 1.9.1 and another issue with 1.9.2.  That lead to **a lot** of people have MASSIVE trouble upgrading. There are +20 questions on so on how to install phpunit like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224338/phpunit-installation-blues , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801183/php-is-there-a-portable-version-of-phpunit/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301639/how-can-i-get-a-phpunit-bat-after-install-phpunit-via-pear/

Comment: Do I have to uninstall pear first before I install it again with the options you mentioned above?

Comment: @Jeune no you shouldn't have too, reinstalling it with --force usually solves the problem

Comment: What a mess, this does not work for me on Ubuntu 12.10 either.  On a side note, PEAR has to be the most awful dependency management scheme ever conceived. I don't understand why it's still in use...

Comment: @btantlinger Most people install PHPUnit using composer nowadays because of the frustration you experienced. No idea why one would use pear today :)

Comment: if you try and install everything using `phpunit/phpunit` it doesn't work, you have to use `phpunit/dbunit`

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Story
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that are running macports, you will have to install the php5-unit-db port to get the needed files. This did help me start looking in the right direction. This dep was not installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve all problems with installing PHPUnit:

```
pear install --alldeps --force phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Answer (score 0):

On the current stable PHPUnit (4.5), DbUnit is an optional package that can be installed with Composer:
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.optional-packages

(click the "Composer" hyperlink if you're not familiar with Composer--I wasn't and it was easy to set up in about 10 minutes)

I struggled before I found that, but was running with an older version of PHPUnit, and had it in a few places, so I removed it from /usr/local/bin and /usr/bin and then followed the instructions "To globally install the PHAR" found here:
https://phpunit.de/manual/4.5/en/installation.html

I didn't have much luck using pear to install PHPUnit.

(I'm on a Mac running Yosemite).